# Blazor Wasm Builds on Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-devops, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm working on CI/CD for a Blazor Wasm Solution written in .Net 5.  This solution contains two web clients and a Shared RCL.  All projects target .Net 5 and have had zero code added since the creation of the projects.  The only changes to the original template are the inclusion of the RCL in the dependencies for each of the Blazor Apps.

Here are their perspective csproj files.

**DanceTrack.WebClient.Shared**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
    
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
      </PropertyGroup>
    
      <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
      </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**DanceTrack.WebClient.Student**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>service-worker-assets.js</ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DanceTrack.WebClients.Shared\DanceTrack.WebClients.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ServiceWorker Include="wwwroot\service-worker.js" PublishedContent="wwwroot\service-worker.published.js" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**DanceTrack.WebClient.Teacher**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>service-worker-assets.js</ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DanceTrack.WebClients.Shared\DanceTrack.WebClients.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ServiceWorker Include="wwwroot\service-worker.js" PublishedContent="wwwroot\service-worker.published.js" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I can build these on my local machine with no issues and then run and load the default Hello World Template as expected.  For some reason, however, I can not get them to build in an Azure Pipeline.

Here is the log output from my build in Azure:

To show that I am targeting .Net 5:

```
Starting: Use .NET Core sdk 5.x
==============================================================================
Task         : Use .NET Core
Description  : Acquires a specific version of the .NET Core SDK from the internet or the local cache and adds it to the PATH. Use this task to change the version of .NET Core used in subsequent tasks. Additionally provides proxy support.
Version      : 2.179.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/AA4xgy0
==============================================================================
A tool to install: .NET Core sdk version 5.x.
Found version 5.0.101 in channel 5.0 for user specified version spec: 5.x
Version 5.0.101 was not found in cache.
Getting URL to download .NET Core sdk version: 5.0.101.
Detecting OS platform to find correct download package for the OS.
/home/vsts/work/_tasks/UseDotNet_b0ce7256-7898-45d3-9cb5-176b752bfea6/2.179.0/externals/get-os-distro.sh
get-os-distro: Error: Distribution specific OS name and version could not be detected: UName = Linux
Primary:linux-x64
Legacy:-x64
Detected platform (Primary): linux-x64
Detected platform (Legacy): -x64
Downloading: https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/a0487784-534a-4912-a4dd-017382083865/be16057043a8f7b6f08c902dc48dd677/dotnet-sdk-5.0.101-linux-x64.tar.gz
Extracting downloaded package /home/vsts/work/_temp/9621c55e-540d-4c16-b98d-ac7a12dca250.
Extracting archive
/usr/bin/tar xzC /home/vsts/work/_temp/308eb00f-3a1a-4cbd-bd6b-86a2a3b2e71e -f /home/vsts/work/_temp/9621c55e-540d-4c16-b98d-ac7a12dca250
Successfully installed .NET Core sdk version 5.0.101.
Creating global tool path and pre-pending to PATH.
Finishing: Use .NET Core sdk 5.x
```

Then I get this in the build stage:

```
Starting: Build
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.179.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet build /home/vsts/work/1/s/DanceTrack.WebClients/DanceTrack.WebClients.Shared/DanceTrack.WebClients.Shared.csproj -dl:CentralLogger,"/home/vsts/work/_tasks/DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b/2.179.2/dotnet-build-helpers/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"/home/vsts/work/_tasks/DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b/2.179.2/dotnet-build-helpers/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" --configuration Release
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.0+126527ff1 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /home/vsts/work/1/s/DanceTrack.WebClients/DanceTrack.WebClients.Shared/DanceTrack.WebClients.Shared.csproj (in 90 ms).
  DanceTrack.WebClients.Shared -> /home/vsts/work/1/s/DanceTrack.WebClients/DanceTrack.WebClients.Shared/bin/Release/net5.0/DanceTrack.WebClients.Shared.dll
  DanceTrack.WebClients.Shared -> /home/vsts/work/1/s/DanceTrack.WebClients/DanceTrack.WebClients.Shared/bin/Release/net5.0/DanceTrack.WebClients.Shared.Views.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:04.43
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/dotnet build /home/vsts/work/1/s/DanceTrack.WebClients/DanceTrack.WebClients.Student/DanceTrack.WebClients.Student.csproj -dl:CentralLogger,"/home/vsts/work/_tasks/DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b/2.179.2/dotnet-build-helpers/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"/home/vsts/work/_tasks/DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b/2.179.2/dotnet-build-helpers/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" --configuration Release
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.0+126527ff1 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /home/vsts/work/1/s/DanceTrack.WebClients/DanceTrack.WebClients.Student/DanceTrack.WebClients.Student.csproj (in 205 ms).
  1 of 2 projects are up-to-date for restore.
##[error]/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/5.0.101/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(387,5): Error NETSDK1082: There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.
/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/5.0.101/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(387,5): error NETSDK1082: There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/DanceTrack.WebClients/DanceTrack.WebClients.Student/DanceTrack.WebClients.Student.csproj]

Build FAILED.

/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/sdk/5.0.101/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(387,5): error NETSDK1082: There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/DanceTrack.WebClients/DanceTrack.WebClients.Student/DanceTrack.WebClients.Student.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.44
```

I've read many articles, but I can't see where I am referencing anything that would break this build, and I would expect it to break locally even if I were.  I am building on Ubuntu 20 Hosted Agent.

Any thoughts on what is causing this issue?

Comment: How about the result for the Private agent or windows hosted agent?